# socialauth-android with single sign on option for facebook and google plus

Tags: android, facebook, google-plus, socialauth

I want to integrate log in with Twitter,Facebook and Google plus option.

i have tried this option

https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

but

it shows log in page in dialog even if Facebook app or Google plus application installed on device.
i want log in should be done via Facebook application installed on device
is there any option to set Single Sign On(SSO) option for loin stage?

Comment: I having issue. Please post your answer if you figure out.